# How to use Pin code authentication in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have quite an unusual question, and I can't find an answer anywhere.

For my project, I need to authenticate users with a `username` and a `PIN` code. I found plenty of examples of how to change `email` into `username`, but I don't know what to do with the `pin` code. In theory, I could use the default `password` in the background but call it a 'pin' on a blade. But I need to make a pin code visible for the admin users. I understand that there is a potential security problem, but this is a requirement.
I can change the default password column in the `User` model:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->custom_password_field_here;
}
```

But how can I avoid password hashing and validate a `pin` with a plain pin in a database?
Is it possible to write custom validate logic with two where causes and validate `username` with a proper `password` and second validate `username` with `pin`?

Comment: plain pin in database? a single database leak can doom everyone in it. fyi, you can create your own authentication provider. alternatively, you can just hook `Auth::login()` to manually logs in user.

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticate-a-user-instance; you can query for a User based on `username` and `pin`, like `$user = User::where('username', $request->input('username'))->where('pin', $request->input('pin'))->firstOrFail()`, then `Auth::login($user)`. Please understand the security holes when using this implementation though; a `pin` is typically too short (4 characters) and too "easy" to crack (4 digits doesn't allow for many permutations, so it can be "brute forced" quite easily).

Comment: Instead of bending your brain trying to think how you can change the scaffolded login boilerplate, just think how you would do it if you had nothing to start with.  1. Create form with username and pin.  Receive the form in the controller. Find the user by their username. check the pin.  If it matches use Auth::login().  BUT RED FLAG.  INSECURE.  At least make sure you rate limit the requests.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How about another solution. Store pin code into `laravel` password column and create another column for the pin and encrypt with 'AES-256'. A standard password will be used for authentication and pin only for displaying pins to the admins? Is this way better than storing plain pins and making them visible on the database?